# React Native: My (created) component isn't found?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I started a new project with `react-native`. I created a component called `Home.jsx` in app/components/home/. It looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>This is the home component!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default Home;
```

And my `index.js` (in the root) file looks like this:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Home from './app/components/home/Home';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Home);
```

When I try to load up the app in the the emulator, I get this error message:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module 
`./app/components/home/Home` from 
`/Users/[my_name]/repos/[repo_name]/index.js`: 
The module `./app/components/home/Home` could not be found from 
`/Users/[my_name]/repos/[repo_name]/index.js`. Indeed, none of these 
files exist:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It maybe because you're exporting the Home class as the default twice, try remove the `export default Home;` at the bottom.

Comment: Hey, tried it and unfortunately it's the same error message!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by not using a folder called `app` and instead using `src`. I'm not entirely sure why this solved the issue but there we go!